# Changing values of a column based on other two column comparison in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series

For the following data table created in pandas,

```
Date        Score    Study_Date
02/2011      70       11/2012   
03/2011      72       11/2012   
10/2011      60       11/2012
12/2011      50       11/2012
01/2012      40       11/2012
02/2012      60       11/2012
03/2012      75       11/2012
11/2012      70       11/2012
12/2012      70       11/2012
01/2013      30       11/2012
02/2013      20       11/2012
04/2013      60       11/2012
06/2013      80       11/2012
```

I would like to replace all the scores for rows whose date is before the study date by 0.

I tried the following:

```
df[df.Date < df.Study_Date, 'Score']=0
```

but I get:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to assign your values, naming the column of interest as the second "argument". The first 2 lines here are just to make sure your date columns are proper `datetime` series (you can skip them if they already are of the correct `dtype`).

```
# Make sure your columns are datetimes:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['Study_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Study_Date)
# Use .loc
df.loc[df.Date < df.Study_Date, 'Score'] = 0

         Date  Score Study_Date
0  2011-02-01      0 2012-11-01
1  2011-03-01      0 2012-11-01
2  2011-10-01      0 2012-11-01
3  2011-12-01      0 2012-11-01
4  2012-01-01      0 2012-11-01
5  2012-02-01      0 2012-11-01
6  2012-03-01      0 2012-11-01
7  2012-11-01     70 2012-11-01
8  2012-12-01     70 2012-11-01
9  2013-01-01     30 2012-11-01
10 2013-02-01     20 2012-11-01
11 2013-04-01     60 2012-11-01
12 2013-06-01     80 2012-11-01
```

That `loc` statement reads as (in pseudo code): Find the values of the column `Score` in dataframe `df`, where `df.Date < df.Study_Date`.

**Issue with your code**

You *could* theoretically do it without the `loc` statement, similarly to what you were trying, but this involves **chained indexing** (`pandas` will give you a warning), and is generally **not recommended**, for [good reason](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy):

```
df['Score'][df.Date < df.Study_Date] = 0
```